# Is there a method for page numbering by chapter in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: page-numbering, libreoffice-writer

Writing a user-manual that is written in chapters, each describing a different aspect of the functions.
Some of those functions are ready and closed, some still in development or ready but not described yet.
Those have to follow the application menu's order, so often will be inserted somewhere in the middle of the document.

A new index by chapters is made, a new alphabetical index as well. 
Each time the page numbering of the existing chapters is changed as well. That forces me to run a new PDF and a full new paper version.

When I could **number by chapter**, I could offer the two new indexes plus the new chapter to be inserted in the paper version.

Once there existed some extension that could handle such a thing for OOo; not downloadable anymore and many version behind anyway. I understood it is available in MS-Office.

Could anyone help me with such a thing? Some workaround maybe, or some method that LibreOffice did not explain in its manual?.

*FYI: this concerns LibreOffice 6.3.5.2. at the moment of writing the most recent stable version.*

Comment: This is a difficult question to read. Starting page numbering over at 1 for each chapter should be straightforward using what is built into LibreOffice. Is that what you are asking? Maybe it would be helpful if you edit the question to shorten it and focus on clearly stating how you want page numbers to work exactly, rather than describing your project in-depth and wondering what extensions or MS Office may do. Side note: Please use "its" properly in a sentence if you plan to write a user manual.

Comment: Changed that "it's", Thanks for notifying @JimK and for editing suggestions.
The manual itself is in Dutch, won't make alike mistakes there.
Even without compact problem description the solution has been given.
Not compact has a reason. Finding remarks on the web, that it was a long desired option in OOo, no mention at all of LO in this respect, I wondered how I could make myself clear. 

From education training, I learned that I should always advance on the question "why would one need such a thing?" _(a remark of a kind I often enough found here)_ by giving the consequence as example.

Comment: My mistake; I did not guess that you weren't writing the manual in English. Glad that @tohuwawohu was able to figure out what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution assumes that you're using the heading styles provided by LO Writer and every chapter starts with a certain, identical heading style (in my example: Heading 1). If so, you can simply edit that heading style:

1. Open Menu "Format" -> "Styles and Formatting..." or hit <kbd>F11</kbd> (you may need to activate the sidebar);
2. Left-click the heading your chapters are starting with; right-click, select "Modify";
3. Select the "Text Flow" tab;
4. Under the "Breaks" section:

   - Tick the "Insert" checkbox
   - Tick the "With paragraph style" checkbox;
   - Select your default page style ;
   - Tick the "Page number" check box.
5. Hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>;
6. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

That's it - now every chapter should start with page number 1.

Comment: Thank you, @tohuwawohu
That something I'd never have found if not for your clear explanation.

Comment: Elegant solution. I was thinking more along the lines of forced page breaks which would have had to be added for each chapter.

Comment: That by itself is a good solution @jimk when you can predict the chapters' respective length. It sure makes generating an alphabetical index much easier.